# Mongoose find for array elements with limit

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using https://mongoosejs.com/ for querying mongo

I want to find data of array elements.Like this:

```
var a = ["a","b","c"];
topic.find({topic:a}).limit(4).exec(.....
```

If I use like this, I can find only for **a** element; but I need altogether. That means:

> limit for a=4 limit for b=4 limit c=4

At stackoverflow you ask a question and we answer the question. Maybe one answer may be 2 may be 3 and stackoverflow send all comments of answers with limit.And i want to do this.

Comment: I do not fully understand what you're asking here. Could you please clarify that a little bit more using examples of input and output json documents?

Comment: i want to find data for all array elements;but i use this code mongodb find only for **a** element;because there is a limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) for this which will give you a single result document:

```
db.collection.aggregate({
    $facet: {
        "a": [{ $match: { "topic": "a" } }, { $limit: 4 }],
        "b": [{ $match: { "topic": "b" } }, { $limit: 4 }],
        "c": [{ $match: { "topic": "c" } }, { $limit: 4 }],
    }
})
```

If you need separate documents you would probably append the following stages at the end of the above pipeline:

```
{
    $project: {
        "result": { $concatArrays: [ "$a", "$b", "$c" ] }
    }
}, {
    $unwind: "$result"
}
```

Comment: error:Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$facet' :D

Comment: Which MongoDB version are you using? `$facet` exists since v3.4.

Comment: may be i change my schemas like this answerschema{comments10:Array,comments20:Array.... }  comments10=first 10 comments comments20=11-20 comments

Comment: No, it's not deprecated. You just need to be on the right version: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#aggregate_Aggregate-facet

Comment: sory sory sory sooo sory man:D my mongodb version is 3.0 :D ty for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution here would be to concatenate the results.

```
const aIds = topic.find({topic:"a"}).limit(4).map( el => el._id );
const bIds = topic.find({topic:"b"}).limit(4).map( el => el._id );
const cIds = topic.find({topic:"c"}).limit(4).map( el => el._id );
topic.find({_id: {$in: aIds.concat(bIds).concat(cIds) }}).exec(.....
```

Not the most efficient, but it will work.

**UPDATE**

Initially, I was not aware that this question related to the mongoose. 
I'm not familiar with it but the idea remains the same:
find 3 topics (a,b,c) each with its own limit then join them.

Comment: @sefereken not sure why this happens. 
What exactly your setup is? Are you using?
Is topic a mongo collection instance?

Comment: y i work with mongo and mongoose for 1 year;but this problem is hard.

Comment: at stackoverflow you ask a question and we answer the question.May be 1 anser may be 2  may be 3 and stackoverflow send all comments of answers with limit(i want to do this:D)

Comment: i have topic schema ,answer schema ,and comment schema.